# How to provide a signed url to Forge API for creating revit file

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I have a API, that allows to upload file using the API and a key in the Headers. 
Can this url be considered as a signed url for the design automation api?

The following is my API request to send the work item.

```
"result":{
           "verb":"put",
           "url":"https://my-website.com/forgeapi/uploadFile",
           "Headers":{
               "apikey":"ASDFFGHJKLLSDFGFAKEHGKEYHGFGHJ"
           }
```

*Please Note*:Here result was declared during creation of activity and consists of the location where I want the file to be uploaded.

I am getting a status as "status": "failedUpload"

And the log says

```
[06/21/2019 10:22:31] Warning: Request failed with Win32 exception, code = 12030, reason = Error 12030 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'..
```

Comment: the URL you showed above doesn't look like signed, and you're passing a header with key... one thing seems strange: the `/` and the end, is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes the / and the end is by mistake, edited it.

Comment: API keys doesn't provide authentication as far my knowledge, please note design automation just passes given authorization information, apart from form-multipart upload, design automation should upload correctly if your authorization information is working correctly on curl or any other rest clients like postman or insomnia.
I recommend you to test with curl/insomnia, try uploading a dummy file.

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala: The upload API works fine when when I run it separately, but after incorporating it with the forge API like shown in the question, it doesn't work

Comment: @JPais, can you please let me know the content-type your upload API is accepting?, what was the response when you tested separately.

Comment: The Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and the response I get is an ID of the file, this ID is used to retrieve the file in another API.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using .NET, I would suggest using the [Design Automation v3 nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation).  You can find a tutorial [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels).